# Glassfish Embedded does not start

Tags: junit, glassfish-embedded, jboss-arquillian

My **glassfish 3.2 embedded** was starting with Arquillian and Junit perfectly and now I've getting this Exception in eclipse. 
I've replace .m2 repository and it doesn't start.
Anybody could help me:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: **Could not setup GlassFish Embedded Runtime**
>   Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.
>   1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scope name given in the descriptor (org.glassfish.hk2.api.PerLookup) did not match the scope annotation on the class (javax.inject.Singleton) in class CommandExecutorImpl
>   2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
>       implementation=com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl
>       contracts={com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl,org.glassfish.embeddable.CommandRunner
>       at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.StaticGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(StaticGlassFishRuntime.java:138)
>       at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer.setup(GlassFishContainer.java:138)
>       ... 62 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this question deleting all workspace project and eclipse .metadata and RemoteSystemsTempFiles folders, after that I've dowloaded all project with "Checkout Project" and the glassfish-embedded using Junit 4 have started normally.